# If $f$ is dynamically coherent, is there a unique invariant foliation tangent to $E^{c}$?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-dynamics

Let $f$ be a diffeomorphism of a closed manifold $M$ such that $f$ is partially hyperbolic if  the tanget bundle of $M$, $TM$ splits into three invariant sub-bunbles

$$
TM = E^{s} \oplus E^{c} \oplus E^{u}.
$$

We say that $f$ is dynamically coherent if there exist $f$-invariant center stable and center unstable foliations $\mathcal{W}^{s}$ and $\mathcal{W}^{u}$, tangent to the bundles $E^{cs}$ (i.e. $E^{c} \oplus E^{s}$) and $E^{cu}$ (i.e. $E^{c} \oplus E^{u}$), respectively; intersecting their leaves one obtains an invariant center foliation $W^{c}$ as well.

> Question: If $f$ is dynamically coherent, is there a unique invariant foliation tangent to $E^{c}$?

At local level there is an anwser in the paper [A non-dynamically coherent example on $\mathbb{T}^{3}$](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0738v1.pdf), that is, if $E$ is a distribution, $\mathcal{W}$ a foliation tangent to $E$ and $W(x)$ is a leaf of $\mathcal{W}$ through the point $x$, $E$ is locally uniquelly integrable at $x$ if any embedded arc through $x$ and tangent to $E$ is contained in $W(x)$.

So, what about the non-local level?